# Rails 6 duplicating and application, impact of webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

A Rails 6 application in a directory that is named as the application would undergo a duplication of that directory & renaming the new one.  This implies editing only the following files, as per conventional rails logic:

```
application.rb
cable.yml
database.yml
config/environments/production.rb
any reference to the versioning and deployment of the application
```

However, the name of the original application is invoked a couple of times in

```
Makefile
package.json
```

the latter is intended to be administrator-editable.  The former not. It is a direct consequence of `webpacker` (notwithstanding a node_modules directory of ~ 72 MB ) being added to the workprocess of rails 6.0

What is the best way and steps to follow to duplicate the application and have two independent applications in their self-named directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the above steps do work in practice.  Leaving it here as a memorandum.

Editing only the following files, as per conventional rails logic:

```
application.rb
cable.yml
database.yml
config/environments/production.rb
any reference to the versioning and deployment of the application
package.json
```

As to the

```
Makefile
```

I preferred emptying out the `node_modules` directory and

```
yarn install --check-files
```

to have that element up-to-date.

Import a copy of database (or whatever the context implies) and `rails s` !